# append svg using jquery;xlink doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I get an svg from backend (using ajax of course):

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0.00 0.00 216.00 153.00"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g id="viewport" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 149)">
    ...
    ...
    <script xlink:href="/js/lib/SVGPan.js"></script>
</svg>
```

I append it to an empty div:

```
$('#svg').append(result);
```

But no request is made for the SVGPan.js file. Can you explain the mechanism behind this and what I can do to force a network request for the SVGPan.js file ?

Thanks

Comment: I used the example from this link: https://code.google.com/p/svgpan/downloads/list. You'll have to download the zip file.

Comment: I suspect you may have to load the script separately, like http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I'm too searching an answer for the same question. For now i know this: 
When you open static svg of html with inline svg with script-xlink in it, script will download and run. When you append svg with script-xlink via jquery, script is not loading.

I have no solution, only workaroud:  put whole script inside `<script><![CDATA[ ... ]]></script>` tag inside `<svg>`, then it will work even when you append svg element via jquery.